# Emulate MUX gate by combinations of XOR, MAJ, or any other

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

What's the smallest combination of XOR and/or MAJ gates (with inversions (NOT) possible at any point) that has the same truth table as a 3 input multiplexer (2x1 MUX) gate?

Which is:

```
s a b MUX
0 0 0  0 
0 0 1  0
0 1 0  1
0 1 1  1
1 0 0  0
1 0 1  1
1 1 0  0
1 1 1  1
```

If it's not possible to emulate it with only XOR and MAJ, how about if we allow ANDs and ORs too?

I know of the form (s*a)+(¬s*b), but is there a shorter equivalent when XORs and MAJs are allowed?

In this case, shorter refers to gate count, not including inversions.

Comment: What is a MAJ? Since modern logic devices would not be implemented in this way, can you explain why this question is important to you? What's the big picture?

Comment: You are really using majority gates??? AFAIK these are relegated in logic theory. However, there's a theorem saying that with XORs you can do *everything*, just like with NANDs; NANDs are easier to manufacture so we use them. As for the question I fear that, like NAND-syntesis, it doesn't have a closed formula so you should attack algebraically the issue

Comment: Well I am looking at [this paper](https://msoeken.github.io/papers/2019_aspdac.pdf) for simplification of a circuit design, which advocates for converting everything into XOR and MAJ first. I can efficiently do that with all kinds of gate types, but the MUX is a bit inefficient (it would be 2 ANDs converted to 2 MAJs with one dangling constant input, and 1 XOR). Was wondering if there's a shorter variant. But maybe it is the most optimal after all.

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio you can't do everythjing with XORs because XOR is a linear operation (mathematically), so non-linear operations (like AND) are impossible.

Comment: What is MAJ?...

Comment: @MituRaj https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majority_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after bruteforcing a bunch of random combinations I've discovered that MUX can be implemented using:

MAJ(XOR(s,a),a,b)

The truth table is the same.

```
sab MUX ^=XOR(s,a) MAJ(^,a,b)
000  0      0          0
001  0      0          0
010  1      1          1
011  1      1          1
100  0      1          0
101  1      1          1
110  0      0          0
111  1      0          1
```